# SQL Server creates dynamic columns Login1, Login2, Login3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a SQL statement that reads this table:

[image: Table1]

And that returns dynamic columns with all the logins in a day, grouping by `EmployeeId`.

```
EmployeeId, Login1, Logoff1, Login2, Logoff2, Login3, Logoff3
```

Comment: How to recognize the User in your table?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed, consider an EmployeeId column in the source table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (EmployeeID INT, LoginTime DATETIME , LogoffTime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
( 49  , '2015-04-07 00:16:22.307' , '2015-04-07 00:16:30.307'),
( 49  , '2015-04-07 00:17:22.307' , '2015-04-07 00:17:39.307'),
( 8   , '2015-04-06 00:16:22.307' , '2015-04-06 00:16:30.307'),
( 8   , '2015-04-07 00:16:22.307' , '2015-04-07 00:16:28.307'),
( 55  , '2015-04-05 00:16:22.307' , '2015-04-07 00:16:22.307')
```

### Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT EmployeeID
     ,Dates
     , Login_Logoff + '_' 
      + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
             (PARTITION BY EmployeeID,Login_Logoff 
                   ORDER BY Dates ASC) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS [Login_Logoff]
FROM @TABLE
 UNPIVOT (Dates FOR Login_Logoff IN (LoginTime,LogoffTime))up
 ) T
 PIVOT (MAX(Dates)
        FOR Login_Logoff
        IN (LoginTime_1,LogoffTime_1,LoginTime_2,LogoffTime_2))p
```

### Results

```
╔════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ EmployeeID ║       LoginTime_1       ║      LogoffTime_1       ║       LoginTime_2       ║      LogoffTime_2       ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║          8 ║ 2015-04-06 00:16:22.307 ║ 2015-04-06 00:16:30.307 ║ 2015-04-07 00:16:22.307 ║ 2015-04-07 00:16:28.307 ║
║         49 ║ 2015-04-07 00:16:22.307 ║ 2015-04-07 00:16:30.307 ║ 2015-04-07 00:17:22.307 ║ 2015-04-07 00:17:39.307 ║
║         55 ║ 2015-04-05 00:16:22.307 ║ 2015-04-07 00:16:22.307 ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                    ║
╚════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, OP needs the logins of a user in a day.

Comment: Amazing! How can I add filters in this SQL? such as TimeSheet.TimeSheetType = 1, TimeSheet.LoginTime between :startDate and :endDate. Also can I make the LoginTime_X dynamic (returning 20 columns if there are 20 different login/logoff for one user?). Also groupying by Date as well (Employee, Date)